Relationship between Katz centrality and degree
Given an undirected graph, we know that the PageRank centrality without damping factor is proportional to the vertex degrees. Is that also true for Katz centrality?

See for example the papers:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.06307
https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.10566
where we analyze exactly this issue.
